# Ruby regular expression exclude multiple items with positive lookahead

Tags: regex, ruby

I would like to exclude multiple items while using positive lookahead `(?=)` in Ruby.

So that we can match newline (`\n`) followed by anything excluding newline and [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), let's say we want to match `em` and `strong`, but not `ul` and `li` as example:

```
\nJuanito
\n<ul>\n    <li>List
\n    </li>
\n    <em>
\n <strong>\n  Fatas!
```

I currently have ([Rubular](https://rubular.com/) requires `\\n` for `\n`):

```
\\n(?=[^\\n])
```

that will match all the newlines as shown below:

- `\nJuanito`
- `\n<ul>`
- `\n    <li`
- `\n    </li>`
- `\n    <em>`
- `\n <strong>`
- `\n  Fatas!`

But I only want:

- `\n` in `\nJuanito`
- `\n` in `\n    <em>`
- `\n` in `\n <strong>`
- `\n` in `\n  Fatas`

Could not figure out how to add a list of things I want to exclude with positive lookahead along with excluding newline.

Also interested in solution without using positive lookahead.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not `\\n(?!\\n)`? Also, if there must be any char after ``\n``, just use ``\\n(?!\\n).``. Or ``\\n(?=(?!\\n).)``

Comment: Ah yea, thanks. But I need to make sure the matching newline is not followed by block-level elements, so I can do something about it.

Comment: `\\n(?!\s*<\/?li)`? See https://regex101.com/r/VOnXIw/1. Besides, are you sure you have `"\\n"`s and not `"\n"`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You maintain the list of rejects *and* union them in negative lookahead:

```
rejects = Regexp.union %w[<ul </ul <li </li]
#⇒ /<ul|<\/ul|<li|<\/li/

input.scan(/\n(?!\n|\s*#{rejects})/)
#⇒ ["\n", "\n", "\n", "\n"]
```